# How can I check data type of node value in cypher query?

Tags: unix, neo4j, cypher

I am having graph database which is collection of events and attendees.

I store `start_time` property of an event as `unix timestamp` so that its easier to search upcoming events just by comparing `unix timestamp`.

Now the problem is by mistake I stored date string as `start_time` value in few events and now I can not compare date string with `unix timestamp`, and thats why query returns no events.

How can I compare data type of start_time property before comparing its value?

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem.

"START attendee=node:attendee('user_id:100001195447969') MATCH (attendee)-[:friends_with]-(friend)-[:attending]-(event) WITH  event,attendee as user, count(distinct friend.user_id) as count WHERE **REPLACE(str(event.start_time),"-","") = str(event.start_time)** AND count >= 1 RETURN event.start_time;"

So now it does not give me events having start_time like "2014-06-05 10:00:00". And I can compare start_time of rest of the events.

Answer (score 3):

You can implicitly check for the property type using the `toInt` function and comparing with the value. To convert all string style `start_time` to their numeric variant:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE has(n.start_time) and (toInt(n.start_time)<>n.start_time)
SET n.start_time = toInt(n.start_time)
```

In case of a lot of nodes use `SKIP` and `LIMIT` to work on reasonable batches.

Comment: "(toInt(n.start_time)<>n.start_time)" condition is not working.

Here is my Query:
"START event=node:event('id:*') MATCH event WHERE (toInt(event.start_time)<>event.start_time) AND event.start_time>=1402702785 RETURN event limit 5;"

Comment: `toInt` has been added IMHO in Neo4j 2.1.x. If upgrading is not an option you could write a short piece of code using GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodes traversing over all nodes and convert the property in question to the desired type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work, but could you compare the value to the value wrapped in a str function? It may not work if the string properties are formatted like unix timestamp, but it's worth a try.

MATCH (e:Event) WHERE e.start_date = str({e.start_date}) RETURN e;